# Kafka streams Top N words in word count

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have implemented the well known example of counting words using kafka streams:

```
KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input", Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));

KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines    
    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
    .groupBy((key, value) -> value)    
    .count();
```

Now I would like to export the top N words with the highest count to a new topic.
What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter all counts above some treshold.

```
textLines.toStream().filter((key, value) -> value > N).to("new-topic")
```

But this, will only return values "more than `N`", not **N values**.

---

Or you can query the statestore using [Interactive Queries](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html), find the total number of entries in the store, then grab the "top N" (after sorting the data)

This is what is done in the [`KafkaMusicExample`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.3.2-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java#L513) to find "top 5 songs played" in a simulated record player.

---

Feel free to checkout the other Confluent examples repo where they have some examples of TopN implementations using a PriorityQueue, such as [this one](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.1.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/TopArticlesLambdaExample.java).

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything I can do with a "foreach" statement on the results? I would rather output them to a topic if possible

Comment: `toStream().to()` does write to a topic; you don't need a foreach. Look at the linked example - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.1.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/TopArticlesLambdaExample.java#L237-L252